# Unable to make MySQL Trigger to work

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've written a simple trigger, but it raises errors I don't get. Heres my trigger:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER logSlette After DELETE on ansatte
for each row 
begin
insert into slettede_ansatte set AnsattID=old.AnsattID,slettet=now()
end;
```

The create table statement for the table is:

```
    CREATE TABLE slettede_Ansatte
 (
 AnsattID Integer(4) NOT NULL,
 slettet TIME NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT Ansatte_PK Primary Key(AnsattID)
 ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: It says "SQL Syntax error near 'end';"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(revised)

The [correct syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) is

```
CREATE TRIGGER logSlette AFTER DELETE ON ansatte
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO slettede_ansatte
       SET AnsattID = OLD.AnsattID,
           slettet=now();
  END;
```

Maybe it is the missing semicolon?

Comment: You need to change the delimiter first - the semicolon will close the CREATE TRIGGER statement (too fast) else.

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench, so how do I change the delimiter? I get this error on the revised code:Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6